# How to name a thread in Windows Performance Analyzer?

Tags: windows, multithreading, profiling, windbg

I was trying to display the names of threads in Windows Performance Analyzer (WPA) (under Windows 8.1). This tool has a column called "thread name".

I followed the famous MSDN article:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xcb2z8hs(v=vs.110).aspx

However, looks like it doesn't work in WPA. And according to a 3rd-party document, only Microsoft’s Visual Studio and WinDbg debuggers support this exception.

So how can I name a thread so that its name can be displayed in WPA?

Answer (score 1):

Starting in Windows 10, version 1607, you can use the SetThreadDescription() API, which is now supported in xperf/WPA:

https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2015/10/26/thread-naming-in-windows-time-for-something-better/

You can also vote for support for it to be added to other Microsoft tools here:

https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/17608120-properly-support-native-thread-naming-via-the-sett

Answer (score -1):

Dont have wpa installed handy so cant answer your query but thanks for
the question it never occurred to me that this could be used native code too 
could come in handy

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
const DWORD MS_VC_EXCEPTION=0x406D1388;
//EmptyBlock,Constant in__except() and lpparam not used in ThreadProc
#pragma warning( disable : 6312 6322 4100 ) 
#pragma pack(push,8)
typedef struct tagTHREADNAME_INFO {
    DWORD dwType; // Must be 0x1000.
    LPCSTR szName; // Pointer to name (in user addr space).
    DWORD dwThreadID; // Thread ID (-1=caller thread).
    DWORD dwFlags; // Reserved for future use, must be zero.
} THREADNAME_INFO;
#pragma pack(pop)
DWORD WINAPI ThreadProc( LPVOID lpParam ) {
    int ch = 0; while(ch != 'y') { ch = getchar(); } return 0;}
void SetThreadName( DWORD dwThreadID, char* threadName) {
    THREADNAME_INFO info; info.dwType = 0x1000; info.szName = threadName;
    info.dwThreadID = dwThreadID; info.dwFlags = 0;
    __try {
        RaiseException( MS_VC_EXCEPTION, 0,
            sizeof(info)/sizeof(ULONG_PTR), (ULONG_PTR*)&info );
    }
    __except( EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_EXECUTION) {    }
}
void main (void) {
    HANDLE hThread = NULL;
    printf("\n\n\n=======Creating Thread And Naming It================\n\n\n");
    if (( hThread = CreateThread(NULL,NULL,ThreadProc,NULL,NULL,NULL)) != NULL) {
        SetThreadName(GetCurrentThreadId(), "\n\nMy New Shiny Thread\n\n");
        WaitForSingleObject(hThread,INFINITE);
        printf("Named Thread Terminated Main is terminating\n");
        CloseHandle(hThread);
    }
}
```

compiled linked and windbagged  **vcpp** event seems to handle this exception in windbg 
wonder what MAGIC Dword **dbce** handles

```
dir /b
compile.bat
threadname.cpp

type compile.bat
@call "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" x86
cl /Zi /nologo /W4 /analyze *.cpp /link /RELEASE

compile.bat
Setting environment for using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 x86 tools.
threadname.cpp

dir /b *.exe
threadname.exe

cdb -c "sxe -c \"~*;gc;\" vcpp;g;q" threadname.exe

0:000> cdb: Reading initial command 'sxe -c "~*;gc;" vcpp;g;q'


=================Creating Thread And Naming It===================


(f84.db4): Visual C++ exception - code 406d1388 (first chance)
.  0  Id: f84.db4 Suspend: 1 Teb: 7ffdf000 Unfrozen "

My New Shiny Thread

"
      Start: threadname!mainCRTStartup (00401642)
      Priority: 0  Priority class: 32  Affinity: 1
y
Named Thread Terminated Main is terminating
quit:
```